# ComboLock code Java

Tags: java

Alright so the program works for the most part but when I test it regardless of if I input the correct code for the combination lock it says it is wrong. The checks are not coming up correctly.

```
 public class ComboLock {
    // ********* you will need to create appropriate instance variables here

    private boolean nutural = true;
    private int position = 0; // current value lock dial is set to
    private boolean flag1, flag2, flag3;
    private int one, two, three;
    private boolean unlock = true;
    ComboLock lock = new ComboLock(35, 12, 37);
    // more variables here ....

    /**
     * Initializes the combination of the lock.
     */
    // **** COMPLETE THIS CONSTRUCTOR - input should be 3 number combination
    // **** You may need to set other instance variables other than the
    // **** arguments here
    // You should verify that the secret number are in the range 0-39
    // (inclusive)
    // if the values given are not in that range, clamp them.
    // i.e. the call new ComboLock(0, -20, 45) would create a combination of
    // 0, 0, 39 (the -20 gets clamped to 0 because it was less than 0)
    // (the 45 gets clamped to 39 because it was > 39).
    public ComboLock(int secret1, int secret2, int secret3) {
        this.one = secret1;
        this.two = secret2;
        this.three = secret3;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the state of the lock so that it can be opened again.
     */
    // ********* COMPLETE THIS METHOD
    public void reset() {
        nutural = true;
        flag1 = false;
        flag2 = false;
        flag3 = false;

    }

    /**
     * Turns lock left given number of ticks.
     *
     * @param ticks number of ticks to turn left
     */
    // *********COMPLETE THIS METHOD
    // you can assume that ticks will be a valid value between 0-40
    // note that 40 ticks in either direction should return us back to the
    // number we started on
    public void turnLeft(int ticks) {
        if (position + ticks < 40) {
            position = (position + ticks);
            flag2 = false;
            if (position == two) {
                flag2 = true;
            }
        } else {
            position = ((position + ticks) - 40);
            flag2 = false;
            if (position == two) {
                flag2 = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns lock right given number of ticks
     *
     * @param ticks number of ticks to turn right
     */
    // *********COMPLETE THIS METHOD
    // you can assume that ticks will be a valid value between 0-40
    // note that 40 ticks in either direction should return us back to the
    // number we started on
    public void turnRight(int ticks) {
        {
            if (nutural) {
                position = (40 - ticks);
                flag1 = false;
                nutural = false;
                if (position == one) {
                    flag1 = true;

                }
            } else {
                if (position - ticks > 0) {
                    position = position - ticks;

                    flag3 = false;
                    if (position == three) {
                        flag3 = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    position = (40 - (ticks - position));
                    flag3 = false;

                    if (position == three) {
                        flag3 = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        if (flag3 = true);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the lock can be opened now
     *
     * @return true if lock is in open state
     */
    // **** COMPLETE THIS METHOD
    public boolean open() {
        if (!(flag1 && flag2 && flag3)) {
            unlock = false;
            System.out.println("Wrong combo :(");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Lock is open!");
        }

        return false; // dummy value for now
    }

    /**
     * Returns current value dial is pointing at
     *
     * @return value dial is pointing at currently
     */
    public int getCurrentNumber() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the combo lock will always consist of 3 numbers

Comment: Your constructor with 3 parameters looks good. As for the question on how to hold to <= 40, you could use Math.min and Math.max

Comment: From the comment on the constructor, it seems like you should be limiting to <= 39 instead of 40

Comment: What's wrong? Unintended behaviour, exception? Why exactly are you asking here about that code?

Comment: 40 is the maxima of the combolock's range. Anything more than 40 or less than 0 will be clamped to the closest number. My problem is whether or not the constructor.